# Angles of a Point with X, Y, Z using GLM

Tags: c++, glm-math

I have two points, one represents the cursor(a cube) and another one represents the position of the Camera.

Now to find out which face the camera is facing I have done something like this

```
    glm::vec3 direction = glm::normalize(cursorPos - cameraPos);
    float angle_x, angle_y, angle_z; 

    angle_x = glm::dot(direction, vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));   // in terms of cosine
    angle_x = glm::acos(angle_x);    // in terms of radians
    angle_x = glm::degrees(angle_x); // in terms of degrees

    angle_y = glm::dot(direction, vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));   // in terms of cosine
    angle_y = glm::acos(angle_y);    // in terms of radians
    angle_y = glm::degrees(angle_y); // in terms of degrees

    angle_z = glm::dot(direction, vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));   // in terms of cosine
    angle_z = glm::acos(angle_z);    // in terms of radians
    angle_z = glm::degrees(angle_z); // in terms of degrees

    bool x_45     = angle_x <= 45; 
    bool x_135    = angle_x > 135;

    bool y_45     = angle_y <= 45; 
    bool y_135    = angle_y > 135;

    bool z_45     = angle_z <= 45;
    bool z_135    = angle_z > 135;


    if (x_45)
    {
        std::cout << "facing left face\n"; 
    }
    else if (x_135)
    {
        std::cout << "facing right face\n";
    }
    else if (y_45)
    {
        std::cout << "facing up face\n";
    }
    else if (y_135)
    {
        std::cout << "facing down face\n";
    }
    else if (z_45)
    {
        std::cout << "facing front face\n";
    }
    else if (z_135)
    {
        std::cout << "facing back face\n";
    }
```

Why do angles that are getting calculated only in the range (0, 180) with the axis?

It's leading to calculated angles as:

"Angle with x: 62.9398 Angle with y: 47.5 Angle with z: 125.464"

Which should only be possible if the calculated angle range is in (0, 360)?

What is happening right now( I assume) is that it's getting calculated without the consideration of another axis, as shown in the below image.

[image]

I am sure this is the most brute way to do this, if anyone has other solution please tell.
--Maybe something like converting that normalized vector in its quaternion rotation represtation and getting euler angels out of it?

Comment: Simple mistake: [`glm::acos`: The range of values returned by this function is \[0, PI\].](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00790.html#gacc9b092df8257c68f19c9053703e2563)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made this code hard to understand and maintain. Here is method which do not need large mind power.

Just 6 vectors defining directions and trying find one which is closest to direction:

```cpp
Facing findOrientation(glm::vec3 direction)
{
    struct FacingNormalizations {
        Facing facing;
        glm::vec3 v;
    };

    constexpr std::array facings {
        FacingNormalizations { Facing::back, { 0, 0, 1 } },
        FacingNormalizations { Facing::right, { 1, 0, 0 } },
        FacingNormalizations { Facing::up, { 0, 1, 0 } },
        FacingNormalizations { Facing::front, { 0, 0, -1 } },
        FacingNormalizations { Facing::left, { -1, 0, 0 } },
        FacingNormalizations { Facing::down, { 0, -1, 0 } },
    };

    auto r = std::max_element(facings.begin(), facings.end(),
        [direction](const auto& a, const auto& b) {
            return dot(direction, a.v) < dot(direction, b.v);
        });

    return r->facing;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/nqjGbMK54

Note if you need to add some extra direction it is easy.
If you like to make some direction more privileged, you should just make respective vector longer.

Using C++20 ranges makes [this code nicer](https://godbolt.org/z/ojvsMYeP1).

Comment: My lack of knowledge led to that sloppy solution, the above solution works out perfectly. I was checking only for the most general direction disregarding their negatives. And the fact that acos only returns (0, 3.14...)  messed it even more. Thank you very much for the neat explanation.